# Binary tree iteration

Tags: tree

If I want to perform add query from Index 0 to an index T. And I have the binary value of T. So for eg I have `0111010` , so it becomes `01110` after removing right most bit.  Taking 0 as left and 1 as right. I add the elements whenever I go right and finally add the element at index T. So does this mean I access BIT[] array whenever I encounter 1 or is there a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

Look I know where this question is coming from. It is of codechef long october. Please refrain yourself for asking questions on live contests.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to modify this approach if it's not right. I have been stuck on this for a long time. It's frustrating me out. Plus it's all about learning. I just wanted to know if we access array only on 1's or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know you will be desperate for the correct logic. I tried pretty hard for this problem, after lot of tries I got an AC (what a feeling!). Don't consider anything about fenwick tree, instead write a simulation for the given calculation.

```
Fdown(i) = (i & (i + 1))
```

Do it in a loop, like

```
cout<<"\n\nEnter L : ";
cin>>l;
while(l > -1)
{
    cout<<bitset<32>(l)<<"\n";
    l = (l & (l+1))-1;
}
```

Enter L in decimal.
You will start seeing what you have to find.
(Don't consider anything else about BIT).

Comment: I tried this but the problem was the decimal value is too big when L is very long. I just tried on my system . Anyways what's the problem with counting no of 1's ?

Comment: @sam First test case is 51491, which is not to big for long int. All other cases can be tested by taking L as long long int. For converting binary to decimal you can use this : http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter. Counting one's won't help since you needn't to count all the ones. When you complete your program, try numbers like 128, 256, 257, 255, etc. Hopefully you will start seeing what you need to find.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I know what you are trying to tell. I tried it before but the problem was in conversion of bitstring to decimal. For small strings it can be done by STL. But the problem lies in big strings. I don't think that even long long is storing them properly. For eg consider a string of around 100 bit length. The decimal equivalent exceeds 18 digits that is even more than what unsigned long long can hold. Is there a way around it ?

Comment: @sam I am not saying that this will give you an AC. I am saying you to try this and try finding a relation between number of 1s in the string and the answer. Try to understand how the  answer is related to the count of 1s and their place in the string.

Comment: I analysed the pattern and know what you were trying to say. Thanks. I had got the AC finally too.